# Communicate between two JavaScript files using AJAX and send data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am able to reach an external JavaScript file A.js from success function of an Ajax call within B.js file. Here is the code from B.js file.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"A.js"
}).done(function(){
    alert("Success");
}).fail(function(){
    alert("Failure");
});
```

I receive alert "Success". Now I want to send data within the above AJAX call to A.js but without using data attribute. I don't want it to be appended to URL. I just want to send something which I have obtained in the B.js file and send it for processing to A.js file. How do I achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Here is my simple A.js file.

```
$("#bookLink").click(function(){
    console.log();      
});
```

I would like this above function, which runs on click of a link, to get value of that link from the AJAX call in B.js file.

Comment: You want to send data from one *file* to another *file* ?  Impossible.  If you want to send data between objects contained within files, you will need to insert the script into the DOM via a `<script>` tag: `var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src='A.js';`

Comment: You can add an object to the global scope and then the script in `A.js` will be able to access it when it loads

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I added a function of my B.js file. Could you please explain more what do you mean by the use of that <script> tag?

Comment: @UnLoCo I already have what I want to send. I am able to get value of it. I just want to send it to another JS file. Any comments?

Comment: I'd probably forget about using jQuery and switch to require.js for something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using AJAX to retrieve your `A.js` file, insert it into your page with a `<script>` tag like so:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = '/path/to/A.js';
script.onload = function () {
    // this will execute when your "A.js" script is loaded into
    // your environment - "A.js" will have the same global
    // object (window) as your "B.js"
}

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

jQuery example:

```
$.getScript('/path/to/A.js', function (script) {
    // fired once the script has been loaded (but not necessarily executed).
});
```

Comment: McMilan Can I use jQuery's getScript to do this? Isn't it similar? Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: @user3044240 Added a jQuery example

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a global variable `global_data` for example and then assign the data to it before loading your `A.js` script

```
//global variable
window.global_data = 'some data';
$.ajax({
    url:"A.js"
}).done(function(){
    //use the variable on script load
    alert(global_data);
}).fail(function(){
    alert("Failure");
});
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the value of the global_data in A.js file?

Comment: Use it normally as you would use any variable